# How to install netfilterqueue

Tags: python, pip, debian-based, kali-linux

```
$ pip3 install netfilterqueue
Collecting netfilterqueue
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/c4/8f73f70442aa4094b3c37876c96cddad2c3e74c058f6cd9cb017d37ffac0/NetfilterQueue-0.8.1.tar.gz (58kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 144kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for netfilterqueue ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-s7oerfb1/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-u29vs26s --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'netfilterqueue' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -ffat-lto-objects -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c netfilterqueue.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/netfilterqueue.o
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_14netfilterqueue_6Packet_set_nfq_data’:
  netfilterqueue.c:2150:68: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘nfq_get_payload’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   2150 |   __pyx_v_self->payload_len = nfq_get_payload(__pyx_v_self->_nfa, (&__pyx_v_self->payload));
        |                                                                   ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                                                                    |
        |                                                                    char **
  In file included from netfilterqueue.c:440:
  /usr/include/libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h:122:67: note: expected ‘unsigned char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
    122 | extern int nfq_get_payload(struct nfq_data *nfad, unsigned char **data);
        |                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_14netfilterqueue_6Packet_4get_hw’:
  netfilterqueue.c:2533:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyString_FromStringAndSize’; did you mean ‘PyBytes_FromStringAndSize’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   2533 |     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(((char *)__pyx_v_self->hw_addr), 8); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 111, __pyx_L1_error)
        |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                 PyBytes_FromStringAndSize
  netfilterqueue.c:2533:15: warning: assignment to ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   2533 |     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(((char *)__pyx_v_self->hw_addr), 8); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 111, __pyx_L1_error)
        |               ^
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyCFunction_FastCall’:
  netfilterqueue.c:6436:13: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))meth’
   6436 |     return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
        |            ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSave’:
  netfilterqueue.c:7132:21: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
   7132 |     *type = tstate->exc_type;
        |                     ^~~~~~~~
        |                     curexc_type
  netfilterqueue.c:7133:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
   7133 |     *value = tstate->exc_value;
        |                      ^~~~~~~~~
        |                      curexc_value
  netfilterqueue.c:7134:19: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
   7134 |     *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
        |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                   curexc_traceback
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionReset’:
  netfilterqueue.c:7141:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
   7141 |     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
        |                        ^~~~~~~~
        |                        curexc_type
  netfilterqueue.c:7142:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
   7142 |     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
        |                         ^~~~~~~~~
        |                         curexc_value
  netfilterqueue.c:7143:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
   7143 |     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
        |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                      curexc_traceback
  netfilterqueue.c:7144:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
   7144 |     tstate->exc_type = type;
        |             ^~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_type
  netfilterqueue.c:7145:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
   7145 |     tstate->exc_value = value;
        |             ^~~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_value
  netfilterqueue.c:7146:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
   7146 |     tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
        |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_traceback
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__GetException’:
  netfilterqueue.c:7201:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
   7201 |     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
        |                        ^~~~~~~~
        |                        curexc_type
  netfilterqueue.c:7202:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
   7202 |     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
        |                         ^~~~~~~~~
        |                         curexc_value
  netfilterqueue.c:7203:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
   7203 |     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
        |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                      curexc_traceback
  netfilterqueue.c:7204:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
   7204 |     tstate->exc_type = local_type;
        |             ^~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_type
  netfilterqueue.c:7205:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
   7205 |     tstate->exc_value = local_value;
        |             ^~~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_value
  netfilterqueue.c:7206:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
   7206 |     tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
        |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_traceback
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py clean for netfilterqueue
Failed to build netfilterqueue
Installing collected packages: netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py install for netfilterqueue ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-s7oerfb1/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-c4a9b5uz/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'netfilterqueue' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -ffat-lto-objects -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c netfilterqueue.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/netfilterqueue.o
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_14netfilterqueue_6Packet_set_nfq_data’:
    netfilterqueue.c:2150:68: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘nfq_get_payload’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     2150 |   __pyx_v_self->payload_len = nfq_get_payload(__pyx_v_self->_nfa, (&__pyx_v_self->payload));
          |                                                                   ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                                                                    |
          |                                                                    char **
    In file included from netfilterqueue.c:440:
    /usr/include/libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h:122:67: note: expected ‘unsigned char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
      122 | extern int nfq_get_payload(struct nfq_data *nfad, unsigned char **data);
          |                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_14netfilterqueue_6Packet_4get_hw’:
    netfilterqueue.c:2533:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyString_FromStringAndSize’; did you mean ‘PyBytes_FromStringAndSize’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     2533 |     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(((char *)__pyx_v_self->hw_addr), 8); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 111, __pyx_L1_error)
          |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                 PyBytes_FromStringAndSize
    netfilterqueue.c:2533:15: warning: assignment to ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     2533 |     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(((char *)__pyx_v_self->hw_addr), 8); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 111, __pyx_L1_error)
          |               ^
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyCFunction_FastCall’:
    netfilterqueue.c:6436:13: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))meth’
     6436 |     return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
          |            ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSave’:
    netfilterqueue.c:7132:21: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     7132 |     *type = tstate->exc_type;
          |                     ^~~~~~~~
          |                     curexc_type
    netfilterqueue.c:7133:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     7133 |     *value = tstate->exc_value;
          |                      ^~~~~~~~~
          |                      curexc_value
    netfilterqueue.c:7134:19: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     7134 |     *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
          |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                   curexc_traceback
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionReset’:
    netfilterqueue.c:7141:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     7141 |     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
          |                        ^~~~~~~~
          |                        curexc_type
    netfilterqueue.c:7142:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     7142 |     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
          |                         ^~~~~~~~~
          |                         curexc_value
    netfilterqueue.c:7143:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     7143 |     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
          |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                      curexc_traceback
    netfilterqueue.c:7144:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     7144 |     tstate->exc_type = type;
          |             ^~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_type
    netfilterqueue.c:7145:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     7145 |     tstate->exc_value = value;
          |             ^~~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_value
    netfilterqueue.c:7146:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     7146 |     tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
          |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_traceback
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__GetException’:
    netfilterqueue.c:7201:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     7201 |     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
          |                        ^~~~~~~~
          |                        curexc_type
    netfilterqueue.c:7202:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     7202 |     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
          |                         ^~~~~~~~~
          |                         curexc_value
    netfilterqueue.c:7203:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     7203 |     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
          |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                      curexc_traceback
    netfilterqueue.c:7204:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     7204 |     tstate->exc_type = local_type;
          |             ^~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_type
    netfilterqueue.c:7205:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     7205 |     tstate->exc_value = local_value;
          |             ^~~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_value
    netfilterqueue.c:7206:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     7206 |     tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
          |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_traceback
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-s7oerfb1/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-c4a9b5uz/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-s7oerfb1/netfilterqueue/
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody else will hit the problem - solution is here: https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue/issues/53

I've passed the challenge on Ubuntu 20.04LTS w/ Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

The error means the package is incompatible with Python 3.7+. Let's see: https://pypi.org/project/NetfilterQueue/0.8.1/ Latest release was at Jan 31, 2017, 3 year ago. Perhaps the package is too old. Try it with Python 3.6.

On the other hand the package can use Cython if it's installed. So try installing the latest Cython and reinstall NetfilterQueue. It could help if newer Cython properly translates `netfilterqueue.pyx` to `netfilterqueue.c`. Try this:

```
pip install Cython
pip uninstall netfilterqueue
pip install netfilterqueue
```

Comment: Try it with Python 3.6.